# detect key event in broadcast receiver in android for emergency caller or sms?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, keyevent

I need to detect key press in a board cast receiver in Android how can I implement this in Android. I have gone through some of the git hub, example but did not find the solution , I try this site [here](http://piergiu.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/android-broadcastreceiver-headset-controls/)

but did no find the solution I need to implement emergency caller that is, if a person is on a dangerous situation and  he need to call help press any button, so that he can send a sms or call to a particular no .ie it can only occur through  the keyevent  in the mobile  is that possible if so how?

Comment: check out this my question 

[keyPadListener in android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678872/how-to-implement-calling-keypad-event-listener-in-android

Comment: i dont under stand ur anser RAshmi

Comment: what i have written in code is that.. register the broadcast receiver in manifest file as shown in question... Then in the broadcast receiver's onReceive() method track the number as shown, in my case i have tracked it "1234".. So what happens is if i dial 1234 my phone i make call button then it will cached by my broadcast receiver, then i can do whatever i want. in my case i have started my activity...  I hope this understands u

Comment: i dial 1234 its just call to 1234  no action is begin taken place

Comment: the code i have written in this way that it will disconnect the call.. just remove the setResultData(null) line.. it wold not disconnect the call.

Comment: i mean the call is going but the the action to occur in the SettingsActivity.class is not working can you please provide ur code

Comment: what exactly you want after the call has made to some number??

Comment: see i just want the key event  as a background service for example if i press key down button let it make a call to particular no right did u get it now?

Comment: so you can set the line like.. setResultData("5678"); so that it will disconnect from 1234 and will make a call to 5678 or set the number whatever you want.. now get it and remove the activity code.. If uou dont want to start activity on that dialled number.. I thin this is clear now..