# Replace default Screen of android incoming and outgoing calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on android. when a calls comes in, I want to replace the default android call screen with a new screen that has answer and deny call options. How can I do that? Need some help. Any help appreciated.

Do I have to use a  toast message for this?

I do have the incoming and outgoing classes.

Comment: why -1? I do have incoming and outgoing call detection.

Comment: I think this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678872/how-to-implement-calling-keypad-event-listener-in-android If you have further queries ypu can ask me in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding goes it is not possible to replace the call screen with an App that is installed over the Marketplace.

To do this you would at least require root permissions. Maybe you also need to reconfigure the Android Version installed on the phone.

Comment: what about trying to add at the top a toast message?

Comment: i need to place in front of the android call screen my own call screen with the accept and reject buttons.

Comment: You can show a toast message, you also could be able to show an activity in front of the original call screen, but you can not have your own working accept and reject buttons.

Comment: and there is no way to use the default buttons (android phonw buttons) but from my app? there is no way to accept or reject the call ?

Comment: Not that I know. This would make it possible to surpress calls and make the phone very useless... therefore it is not allowed with a standard app.